# Problema com o operador de expoente em função

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, funções, operadores

```
destaquei o problema e descrevi na equação: 
M = 1000/(10 - Vinc(10)**2/299792458**2)**(1/2)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

#Função de Progreção aritmética com rasão = 10, Retornando em Vf (Velocidade pós aceleração).  
def Vinc(V):
    X = 2
    while(X <= 1):    
        X += 1
        V += 10
        return(V)


leitura =[]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
contador = 0
eixo_x = 50
while True:           
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim([0,eixo_x])   #faixa do eixo horizontal
    ax.set_ylim([0,1023]) # faixa do eixo vertical

    #O problema está aqui, Vinc(10) não pode ter expoente pois a função não aceita esse operador.
    M = 1000/(10 - Vinc(10)**2/299792458**2)**(1/2) 

    print(Vinc(10),'______',M)
    leitura.append(M)  #teste com numeros aleatorios
    #leitura.append(dados)     
    ax.plot(leitura)
    plt.pause(.000001)     
    contador = contador + 1
    if (contador > eixo_x):
        leitura.pop(0)
```

## **

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar agradeço desde já! 
Muito obrigado, atenciosamente: letalboy ;)
**#

Comment: Creio que sua função Vinc está errada. Como você parte de X = 2 e vai incrementando este X dentro do loop ele logicamente nunca atenderá à condição (X <= 1). Provavelmente entrará em um loop infinito até ocorrer um overflow. Mas tem um outro problema: você faz um loop mas colocou o return dentro desse loop, o que não faz sentido. Outra coisa: creio que 299792458**2 causará overflow. Dê uma estudada nos limites numéricos que você pode representar com cada tipo de dado em sua linguagem.

Comment: Obrigado, estudarei a respeito ;)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, minha primeira pergunta é:

A lógica de sua função Vinc esta certa?,

```
    def Vinc(V):
        X = 2     //você definiu X =  2,
        while(X <= 1):   //você testou se X é <= 1, o que é false pois X = 2
                         // logo você não entra no loop   
            X += 1       // Incrementa x de maneira que irar gerar um loop infinito
            V += 10
            return(V)   //retorno dentro do loop, ou seja, loop só executaria uma vez.
```

Como acho que deveria ser:

```
def Vinc(V):
    X = 2
    while(X >= 1):    
        X = X - 1
        V += 10
    return(V)
```

Agora respondendo sua pergunta,

Uma maneira de resolver é quebrar sua linha de código em duas, sendo assim:

```
temp =  Vinc(10) 

M = 1000/(10 - temp**2/299792458**2)**(1/2)
```

Comment: Obrigado, Creio que agora funciona! ;)